# Can I use both SIP and P2P for VoIP?

Tags: java, android, sip, p2p

I'm trying to build a VoIP application and VoIP need a callee's IP to make end to end communication. So my idea is:

1. Use SIP for getting callee's IP via SIP server.
2. When I have calless's IP, use P2P to make `Audio` communication.

Can I do that?

Comment: Yes. Though depending on what callee IP, you get, you may or may not be able to initiate a P2P session to the callee.  It'll be up to the callee to ensure a path is available from the caller.

Comment: When you log in into a program, you will send a signal to SIP server right?. That how does SIP server get your IP right?

Comment: It really depends on which flavor of SIP you're using.  If its TCP based you won't have to worry about anything I'm about to mention.  If its UDP based, the callee could present an IP which the caller cannot contact the callee on.  If so its not a big deal, it just means the burden of configuring a valid IP path is on the callee.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. But is there any technique to find an IP behind proxy or firewall or NAT?

Comment: Not without installing special software on the device behind that firewall/proxy etc. to communicate that to your outside program.  And there wouldn't be much point in it really.  IP and Port forwarding rules are the way to handle this.  That way you talk to the device behind the firewall by communicating with its public IP:port combination.  No need to know the IP address of the device on that private network.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is: [ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment)

In a VoIP network, more then 90% of both the bandwidth and CPU power are spent for media handling (not for the signaling). There are SIP servers which can handle billions of simultaneous user registrations and millions of simultaneous calls (on a single server, without media routing) . So the important thing worth to be optimized is the media routing, not the signaling. And for this we already have an established protocol named [ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment). This is capable to route the media P2P most of the time (and when not -for restricted NAT's- it uses [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT)). The same is used nowadays also in WebRTC.